# C++ cross-platform development to avoid preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I need to maintain a project that supports running on Linux and Windows. Some codes using preprocessor directives like this are fine.

```
#ifdef _WIN32 // _WIN32 is defined by Windows 32 compilers
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

But some are the actual implementation, which I would like to prevent using preprocessor directives.

```
void Foo()
{

    #ifdef _WIN32 // _WIN32 is defined by Windows 32 compilers
    code for windows 
    #else
    code for Linux
    #endif

    some common code...

    #ifdef _WIN32 // _WIN32 is defined by Windows 32 compilers
    code for windows again
    #else
    code for Linux again
    #endif

}
```

So things get convoluted and harder to maintain. Is there any better way?

Comment: Interfaces + abstraction layers where the platform specific code is contained within implementation files that can be excluded by your build system based on the platform you are currently building for.

Comment: If you want a real-world example, you could take a look at the Doom3 source: They do stuff similar to what @Chad described. https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl/tree/master/neo/sys

Comment: Sticking with the standard libraries is going to get you a long way. The most pervasive multi-plaform project I've ever worked on covered eleven distinct targets, and in the end, some things are simply not possible to avoid (such as dynamic library loading, which, on an AS/400, is something you have to see to believe). Unless absolutely nothing else is available, avoid `#ifdef` coding on a platform basis. Explore doing it on a *feature*-enablement basis if you are considering it as a no-other-choice scenario. Ex. your code: `#ifdef HAS_STDINT_H` etc.

Comment: See [#ifdef Considered Harmful (pdf)](http://www.ethernut.de/pdf/ifdefs.pdf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The traditional way is to "hide" all the code that is specific to any OS in wrapper functions - you can either do that in complete functions that do a higher level functionality - e.g. have a function that returns all directory entries based on a given path as input, or implement the individual base-functions, e.g. `start_read_directory(path)`, `read_dir_entry()`, `end_read_directory()` - that's just an example functionality, the same principle(s) can be applied on almost any system specific functionality. Wrap it enough, and you wouldn't be able to tell what you are programming for.

In essence, you are doing it wrong if you have a lot of #ifdef in the code itself.

Answer (score 8):

Handle the OS specifics from the build system, not the code. For instance, have two versions of Foo.cpp: one that gets compiled on Linux and another on Windows. Ideally, the header file will be common and all function signatures identical.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a simplified version of the factory pattern.

Have a common interface

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};
```

And for each platform you create a specific class

```
#import <windows.h>
class MyClassWindows : MyClass
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() { /* Do something */ }
};

#import <linux.h>
class MyClassLinux : MyClass
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() { /* Do something */ }
};
```

Then when you need this class, you use your factory:

```
class MyClassFactory
{
public:
    static MyClass* create()
    {
        #if defined _WIN32
            return new MyClassWindows();
        #elif defined _LINUX
            return new MyClassLinux();
        #endif
    }
}
```

There a many variants of this methods, including defining the MyClassFactory::create method in the .cpp of each platform-specific class and only compiling the .cpp for the appropriate platform. This avoids all preprocessing directives, the switching is made by choosing the correct implementation file.

Comment: Doesn't this introduce runtime virtual function costs as well as a layer of inheritance that's somewhat superfluous when you'll never run on two platforms simultaneously?

Comment: It does, but IMHO it is a small cost for readability and ease of maintenance (this is my opinion, it is subjective). By skipping the inheritance and only implementing different .cpp files for the same header file as suggested in some answers, you may end up with linking errors instead of clear compilation error when you add new methods and forget them in some platforms. Additionally, it allows sharing all the common code in the base class and it is clear which file contains which methods. Finally, If a platform needs some private methods, those are easy to put in the platform specific class.

Answer (score 4):

A common pattern would be to provide system independent header files, and platform-specific implementation files.

Nothing platform specific in the header:

```
class Foo
{
   ...
};
```

In two different implementation files, foo_linux.cpp

```
 Foo::Foo() { .. linux code }
```

foo_windows.cpp

```
Foo::Foo() { .. windows code }
```

and maybe platform independent implementation in foo.cpp

```
void Foo::plat_independent_function()
```

Your platform builds then link in foo.cpp and foo_platform.cpp

Answer (score 0):

A possibility for the implementation of this is to use the PIMPL idiom, where your class just publishes the "interface" and declares a meaningless pointer to an implementation class (in its dark, hidden and private corner) and the build system takes care of pulling in the correct platform dependent code for the class containing the implementation of your PIMPL.